# Center Contents heading in tocloft v2.3f

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, tocloft

In the past, I believe this technique was used to center the Contents heading in the table of contents via [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill \Huge}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}
\chapter{Chap 3}

\end{document}
```

However I recently updated the package to version v2.3f (2013-05-02) and this no longer centers the heading.

[image: contents]

How do I fix this? The answers for a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835620/how-can-i-centre-the-title-of-the-table-of-contents-in-latex) do not work.

Comment: You can use `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil \Huge}`. Than you don't need any `\cftaftertoctitle`

Comment: I had the same problem, but while the solution suggested below worked in the example it did not work for my project. Instead I added an empty `\hbox{}` to `\cftaftertoctitle` to make it `\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\hbox{}}`. Then the title was centered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117998/center-contents-heading-in-tocloft-v2-3f#comment262230_117998) by [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel), the following modification works.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil \Huge}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}
\chapter{Chap 3}

\end{document}
```

[image]