# How do I center the table of contents title using tocloft?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, tocloft

I'm getting odd behavior using package `tocloft` to format my table of contents and center the titles "Contents", "List of Figures", and "List of Tables". Using the code suggested in the `tocloft` documentation, I tried to center "Contents" with:

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
```

but instead of centering, this right justifies the title, even though the exact same code works to center the list of figures and list of tables titles.

In my minimal working example, I can get this working by replacing the first `\hfill` with `\hfil`, but in my actual document that fix causes the title to be somewhere in between left and center. I am trying to understand why `\cfttoctitlefont` is not working the same as `\cftlottitlefont` and `\cftloftitlefont`, so that I can address the problem in my actual document.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\section{Section}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Example table]{This is a table.} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Perfect answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117998/center-contents-heading-in-tocloft-v2-3f

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's indeed something in the example code of the `tocloft` package that's not quite correct about how to get the string "Contents" centered on a line. Anyway, you can achieve your objective by issuing the commands

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
```

Note the `\hfill` inserted *after* "Contents". If you would rather have the string "Contents" be set in normal size and normal weight, you'd use `\normalfont\normalsize` instead of `\bfseries\Large`.

A full MWE, applying these changes to the header of the List of Tables as well:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill\bfseries\Large List of Tables} % no \hfill after "List of Tables"...
%%% using the command "\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\bfseries\Large}" works too...
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\section{Section}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | r |}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[Example table]{This is a table.} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked for my actual document as well.

Comment: The 10th upvote on this answer, on 2018-08-16, earned me badges 1,110 and 1,111 [!] on this site. Many thanks!!!

Comment: This almost worked for me, but if the List of Tables is included in the TOC, it takes the same centered bold text. Do you know how to make it suck that i can keep the contents of the TOC as it is? If the question is not clear let me know and i will clarify

Comment: @AustinBenny - I'm not sure I understand what "the list of tables [being] included in the ToC entails. Pleaese post a *new query*, in which you'd explain what exactly you're doing and what you are looking to achieve. Incidentally, by posting a new query, far more people will get to see what you're looking to achieve, thus considerably raising the odds that someone will be able to come up with a solution.

Comment: @Mico got it. Here is the question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638149/how-to-center-the-list-of-tables-title-in-such-a-way-that-the-section-list-of-t

Comment: You don't want to modify the formatting internally to `\contentsname` itself, in case you need it in some other place (especially the toc itself). However, the bug mentioned in the original post must have been fixed, because the code works flawlessly.

Answer (score 8):

Actually your solution is almost correct. The reason why it is not working is the fact that LaTeX removes the horizontal space that comes at the end of a line. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45952/16757) further elaborates on this fact but to prevent this either you need to insert a dummy text -- e.g., `\null{}`, `\mbox{}`, `\hfill` -- after the last `\hfill`:

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill\hfill} %Note the second \hfill, it could have been any dummy text
```

and [Mico's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142451/16757) effectively does that by ending `\contentsname` with an `\hfill` and simultaneously setting `\cftaftertoctitle` to `\hfill`.

Or, you could use `\hspace*{\fill}` so that your code becomes:

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{\fill}\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}
```

and Mico's solution becomes:

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace*{\fill}\bfseries\Large Contents\hspace*{\fill}}   
%\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}} % Alternatively, you can delete the last \hspace*{\fill} from the above line and uncomment this line.
```

This last `\contentsname` definition works with both `tocloft` package and the original LaTeX toc command as well.

Comment: For me, `\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\bfseries\huge}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}` works perfectly (I do not need to add any dummy text after the second `\hfill`).

Answer (score 1):

Simply using the following works too:

```
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Contents}
```

Comment: This only works if you're *not* using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft).

Comment: If you need `\contentsname` in the toc, for example, you will get the issue in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638149/how-to-center-the-list-of-tables-title-in-such-a-way-that-the-section-list-of-t.