# How to center the List of Tables title in such a way that the section "List of Table" is not affected in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, tocbibind

This is a follow up question to this discussion: [How do I center the table of contents title using tocloft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142445/how-do-i-center-the-table-of-contents-title-using-tocloft/142451?noredirect=1#comment1590804_142451)

I can center the List of Figures as seen below
[image]

But it shows up in the TOC kinda "funky" as seen below (what it does now and what i would like to change)

[image]

I would LIKE the output to look like this

[image]

The code i am using:

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries\Large Table of Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill\bfseries\Large List of Tables\hfill} % no \hfill after "List of Tables"...
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hfill\bfseries\Large List of Figures\hfill} % no \hfill after
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}
```

Is there a fix to this?

I am using Pdflatex with the article document class. I had to include this code after the preamble (the things above are in the preamble) to add the lof,lot to the TOC.

```
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

I am using the package

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

to add the items to the TOC.

Comment: Please tell us (a) which document class you employ (it may not be compatible with the `tocloft` package) and (b) what you had to do, in terms of coding, for the "List of Tables" and "List of Figures" to show up in the ToC.

Comment: @Mico, done. Made the edits

Comment: @SimonDispa not sure i understand. I have those lines in my code and it is still producing the output in the second picture. Are you saying remove the \hfill after list of table?

Comment: without having tried it: what happens if you use `\begin{center}List of Figures\end{center}` or `{\centering List of Figures}` (extra {}!). I wouldn't expect a better result but maybe?

Comment: @flukx error on both :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is in part taken from [center ToC title using tocloft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142451/161015)

[image: e]

[image: x]

[image: z]

To have the `Table of Contents`, `List of Figures`, and `List of Tables` as titles centered on their respective pages using `tocloft`, you can use the solution provided in the answer cited above.

To have  "List of Figures' and "List of Tables" **in the ToC** add `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}` to your document. (see the example)

**Do not use**  `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%%% \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % DO NOT USE <<<<<<<

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\bfseries \hfill Table of Contents\hfill}   
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\hfill\bfseries\Large List of Tables} % no ending \hfill <<<<<<
\renewcommand{\cftafterlottitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\hfill\bfseries\Large List of Figures} % no ending \hfill <<<<<<
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}


\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
        
    \newpage
    \section*{Signature Block}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Signature Block}
    \newpage
    \section*{Record of Revision}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Record of Revision}
    
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \listoffigures
    
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \listoftables
    
    \newpage        
    \section*{Glossary}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Glossary}
    \newpage        
    \section{Introduction}
    \newpage
    \section{Methodology}
    
                
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \caption{A}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \caption{B}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \caption{C}
    \end{figure}

    \newpage
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \caption{A}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \caption{B}
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \caption{C}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see the "List of Tables", "List of Figures" in the TOC. I have edited my question to show the output i am looking for.

Comment: After some more digging, i forgot to mention that i am also using the package \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} to add the lof,lot to the TOC

Comment: @Austin Benny  Please see the updated answer.