# How to move 'Contents' to the middle of the page

Tags: table-of-contents

I need to move the word 'Contents' to the middle of the page.
[image]

In the photo it is displayed in the left side of the page. Is it possible to move it to the middle of the page?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\large}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\doublespacing
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
\singlespacing
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\section*{Test}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test}
\section*{Test}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test}
\section*{Test}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test}
```

Comment: See the answers to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117998/center-contents-heading-in-tocloft-v2-3f) question.

Comment: Answer from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117998/center-contents-heading-in-tocloft-v2-3f) question helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\large}
\title{Title} % <-- add this line to make the file compilable
\author{Author} % <-- add this line to make the file compilable
\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\doublespacing
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill Contents\hfill}   % <-- centering the title

\tableofcontents
\endgroup
\singlespacing
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\section*{Test}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test}
\section*{Test}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test}
\section*{Test}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]